# Generic type conversion in Golang

Tags: go, generics, type-conversion

I got tired to write manual slice conversions like []int32 -> []int64, because there are many situations when you need to do use slice with another type.
So I tried to write a generic function for that:

```golang
func convertSlice[T1 any, T2 any](t1 []T1) []T2 {
    t2 := make([]T2, len(t1))
    for i := range t1 {
        t2[i] = T2(t1[i])
    }
    return t2
}
```

and want to use it like

```golang
a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
var b []int64 = convertSlice[int, int64](a)
```

But I cant compile it, compiler says that `./prog.go:8:14: cannot convert t1[i] (variable of type T1 constrained by any) to type T2`

So, how can I fix that?

Live example: https://go.dev/play/p/YYOLFjYt4mq

Of course, I can write separate functions for every primitive type like:

```golang
func convertNumericSlice[T1, T2 constraints.Integer | constraints.Float](t1 []T1) []T2 {}
func convertStringSlice[T1, T2 ~string](t1 []T1) []T2 {}
```

but that doesnt look like cool generic way at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to convert type parameters with arbitrary constraints. The spec mentions that ([conversions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions)):

> [...] x can also be converted to type T if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - Both V and T are type parameters and a value of **each type in V's type set can be converted to each type in T's type set**.

If both `T1` and `T2` are constrained with `any`, both type sets are virtually include any possible type.

Even though a particular instantiation of your `convertSlice` function may be valid, the compiler can't statically prove that the conversion `T2(t1)` is **always** valid. In theory you could instantiate `convertSlice[string, chan func()]` and then a string obviously can't be converted to a channel of functions.

The only way to write a catch-all function is to use reflection with the [`CanConvert`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.CanConvert) method, but you would be left with deciding how to handle the case where `CanConvert` returns `false`. Panic? Return a zero value?

If you choose to use generics, you are already making a choice towards type safety, so introducing reflection seems counter-intuitive. With generics, you do have to write functions for each set of convertible underlying types. The main special cases are:

Numbers:

```
type Number interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float
}

convertNumbers[T1, T2 Number](t1 []T1) []T2 {}
```

Strings — it is special-cased for byte slices and rune slices, but byte slices and rune slices aren't convertible to each other, so you'd need two functions here):

```
convertStrings[T1, T2 ~string | ~[]byte](t1 []T1) []T2 {}
// or
convertStrings[T1, T2 ~string | ~[]rune](t1 []T1) []T2 {}
```

Complex:

```
convertComplex[T1, T2 ~complex64 | ~complex128](t1 []T1) []T2 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a type with all number types then it's possible to convert in between.

Try like below:

```
type Number interface {
    int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64 | float32 | float64
}

func convertSlice[T1 Number, T2 Number](t1 []T1) []T2 {
    t2 := make([]T2, len(t1))
    for i := range t1 {
        t2[i] = T2(t1[i])
    }
    return t2
}
```

[Go play ground demo](https://go.dev/play/p/m_Mui77DZ9u)

Comment: I dont want to have separate conversion functions for numbers and strings, I want to have exactly one function for all types